# So is it an abuse of privilege to make trivial changes that will save my sanity?

Tags: discussion, edits

<strike>So</strike> I've earned my edit badge or whatever you call it and the one thing that most gets up my nose is questions starting with **So**. If I edit it out whenever I see it would I be abusing this hard-earned privilege?

I know the guidelines state that trivial changes are discouraged but to me this is **not** trivial.

Both my parents were teachers and they would be mortified to see so many questions starting this hideous way.

Comment: ̶S̶o̶ if there are other things in the post to fix then fix them too.  If that is the only thing there you're better off leaving it alone...

Comment: So many edits! Ha! Edit that one!

Comment: @animuSOn ...with SO being a part of your name, we should have expected this.

Comment: That truly gets up my nose as well but it's a trivial edit, I wouldn't go out of my way to hunt and kill.

Comment: So, I also hate SO sos, so much so I actually asked on the [English stackexchange about what it was called](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43273/sentences-beginning-with-so).

Comment: Just editing out "So" is a trivial edit - but so help me, every time I come across the word "Greetz", it's going.

Comment: I can't help noticing this everywhere now, so I can thank you for that. It's just as annoying as bad kerning http://xkcd.com/1015/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having read your question, I would say there is no problem in editing it out. But don't let that be all you edit.

If the question/answer is otherwise perfect, fine. But if there are other obvious issues (and there most likely will be at least some), please edit those as well.

Comment: @Paul That took you way too long to edit. ;) Btw, no need to add any indication of you editing something to the content itself. You can leave that message in the edit summary.

Comment: Took too long and got it wrong - then @Popular Demand  changed it again (quite rightly) ... oh well ... the consensus seems to be `yes but so long as there's more edits required` which I'm happy with.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that a leading 'so' is nearly wrong enough to deserve an edit, unless you are otherwise doing a major rewrite job. Any author would be well within their rights to revert your edit if that's (nearly) all you do. It may not be your preferred diction, but it's not a giant waste of space or horribly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem problem with trivial edits is that users below 2k aren't actually editing anything: they're *proposing* edits, which then have to be voted on by others. Filling up the queue with minor edits will lead to edit-approving burn-out, which is as good a reason as any to discourage the practice.

The other problem with trivial edits is that it rapidly ups the revision counter towards [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) status. If you take out /^So/ and three other people change a punctuation mark each, it takes a moderator to unflag the post as a wiki. Users don't gain rep for wiki posts, and fixing things after the fact just means work for someone else.

In other words, while I might argue with some of the inflection points (e.g. how many votes an edit needs, or how many changes trigger wikification) I think the idea of not creating make-work for other people is a worthwhile goal.